# mod_rewrite - how to avoid infinite loop

Tags: .htaccess, loops, recursion, url-rewriting, infinite

I want to have a nice URLs on my website, so I have added this line into .htaccess, but it's causing infinite loop.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/pages/$1%{QUERY_STRING}.php
```

It should rewrite every URL and add "pages/" and ".php" extension but only FIRST TIME not like some kind of recursive function.

Comment: You're rewriting from any file whatsoever to that new file, which just so happens to be any file whatsoever.

Comment: I have found a solution - add RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

Comment: It works on the most of pages, but on home page and some other random page it gets 500 internal error. is any better solution?

Comment: Solved :P   http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?page=2&cid=51C62

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to pass the query string, that happens automatically.

[see the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

other than that, try this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/pages/$
RewriteRule ^(/.*)? http://www.mydomain.com/pages/$1 [L]
```